# How to add a folder as entry in npm package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, yarnpkg

I am trying to publish a npm module. Which has a following folder structure.
[image]

In my `package.json` it has `"main": "./dist/"` I understand this resolve for `index.js`. But in the dist folder I have individual files named as `string.js`, `class.js`, `dom.js` I am planning to import them as
`import { isValidZipCode } from '@scope/utils/string';` but right now I have to import them as `import { isValidZipCode } from '@scope/utils/dist/string';`

Is there a way I can resolve a folder when I import a module from `node_modules`?

EDIT: Main idea is to import the files as `import { isValidZipCode } from '@scope/utils/string'` when I keep individual files for individual exports.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to make a index file in root folder then just export all files with the following:

In your `dist/string` export each method/function on it, and for the index do it follows:

```
export * from "./dist";
```

as it helps maintain code and looks cleaner to eye

Regards :)

Comment: then import them as 
`import { isValidZipCode } from '@scope/utils/string'`?

Comment: Throwing error, cant resolve `./dist`. I am assuming its looking for a index.js in dist which isnt available in dist.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct for the most part, but I think there's one thing that's missing (either from your OG post or from their answers), which is:

1. Your folder structure is definitely not standard, which likely led to your current problems as well as non-helpful results in the Google searches when you tried to find an answer.
2. You didn't show your `package.json` nor your `webpack.config.js` file contents, which are the key to answering your question even if you did have such a weird file structure.

Some suggestions:

1. Change your folder structure to be something along the lines of

   ```
   /
   |--src
       |--utils
           |--string.js
           |--[... other js files]
           |--index.js
   |--dist (will be generated automatically)
   |--[config files, like package.json, webpack.config.js, etc]
   ```
2. Make your webpack.config.js have something along the lines of:

   ```
   output: {
       path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
       //...
   }
   plugins: [
       new CopyWebpackPlugin({
           patterns: [
               'ReadMe.md', // optional
               'package.json',
               'LICENSE.md' // optional
           ]
       })
   ],
   ```

   In order to fix/normalize the output (e.g. output would be `/dist/utils/[string.js, ...], /dist/package.json`).

   Then, make your package.json main something like

   ```
   "main": "utils/string.js"
   ```

After doing that, your output should look something like

```
/
|--src
    |--utils
        |--string.js
        |--[... other js files]
        |--index.js
|--dist
    |--utils
        |--string.js
        |--[... other js files]
        |--index.js // optional: only if you want to support stuff like
                    // `import { isValidZip } from '@scope/utils';`
    |--package.json
|--[config files, like package.json, webpack.config.js, etc]
```

Finally, you need to `cd dist` and run `npm publish` from inside there. (That's why you need the package.json inside that directory.)

I can't really go into details about the `@scope` portion since I haven't done that myself, but I did the above for one of my own projects and it worked as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Create a `index` file in `root` folder then just export all files like this

```
export { default as Str } from "./dist/string";
export { default as Cls } from "./dist/class";
export { default as Dom } from "./dist/dom";
```

and also update `package.json` change `main` from`./dis/` to `./`

Hope this will help you. Happy coding.

Comment: Umm yup this would do the trick, but you have to import them as
`import { isValidZipCode } from '@scope/utils'` but not as `import { isValidZipCode } from '@scope/utils/string'`, right?

Comment: @SubhenduKundu yes if index file create on utils folder

Comment: Gotcha, but I am trying to import them as `'@scope/utils/string'`, I know it sounds silly but is that possible?

Comment: @SubhenduKundu create folder by the name of string and create index file in it.
in that file just import `export { default as Str } from "../dist/string";`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191352/discussion-between-rai-talha-rehman-khan-and-subhendu-kundu).